# Use Cloud Composer with Celery Executor to run job on remote worker in secured network

Tags: python, celery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

We are running a Cloud Composer setup on GCP and want to run a remote ETL job in a secured environment on premises.
Cloud Composer uses Redis which is running on the K8S cluster.

We can **not** connect to it via VPN.

How can we use our master node on GCP to allow the remote worker to interact with it?

Can we safely expose our Redis?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a password that Airflow will provide Redis to access it. You can also set cloud permissions so that only your Airflow machines will have access to the Redis machine or access to the Redis ports on the machine that it's posted on.

You will add significant latency by having it connect to an on premises machine though.

Comment: Would you please link to documentation? I only found this regarding connecting to the Redis instance in the Composer GKE cluster: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/connecting-redis-instance#connecting-cluster

Comment: This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#connecting_to_the_flower_web_interface) mentioned  how to connect to the Flower web interface, a web-based tool for working with Celery clusters, is this what you are looking for?